# S3 Object cannot be viewed from browser in ClientVPN Private Subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc, aws-vpn

We've a local system server in AWS VPC Private Subnet, and we have configured AWS ClientVPN to access that instance with that VPN Client called **Pritunl**. And we've stored all of documents and images in AWS S3 that configured with VPC Endpoint regarding that documentation https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-private-connection-no-authentication

Problem is everything is working fine as accessing that server with browser when we connect VPN Client to that server. But we cannot access to S3 Object in browser `https://myprivatebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/images/bd3c6d93-ed68-48c8-939c-91bdcb3e6b6b.png` as that image cannot be displayed or downloaded in browser. But when I ssh to that server and type `wget https://myprivatebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/images/bd3c6d93-ed68-48c8-939c-91bdcb3e6b6b.png`, that image was downloaded successfully.

Please let me know how to make how to display or able to download that object from browser.

Comment: What does "cannot be displayed or downloaded" mean?  What is the exact error or other undesired behavior?

Comment: When I tried to open/download that image in terminal like `wget https://.....` it was working. But when I try to open/download at browser, page is still loading and take long and got response timeout.